# Reading value from struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to read a year from a struct to check whether that year is a leap year.

My code at the moment is:

```
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

} date;
```

And the place to read it in is:

```
  int is_date_valid(date *d) {

    printf("Year = %d\n", d.year);
    //Checking if year is a leap year
    if ( d->year%400 == 0)
        printf("%d is a leap year.\n", d.year);
    else if ( d->year%100 == 0)
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", d.year);
    else if ( d->year%4 == 0 )
        printf("%d is a leap year.\n", d.year);
    else
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", d.year); 



 return 0;
}
```

At the moment, the year is not being read in (the year is being entered by the user and this function is called from the main). I'm not sure how to call the year from the struct to be tested in this function. I'd really appreciate any help anyone can give! thanks

Comment: I didn't get what your problem is. What is this `is_date_valid` function supposed to do? Wouldn't you need to convert `formatted_date` into something else?

Comment: You declare a `date d`, but don't set any values in it before using it. You also don't do anything with the `formatted_date` parameter. So I don't think it is clear what this function is needing to do.

Comment: Your local `d` variable is not being initialized, so of course that's not going to work. Presumably you want to use your `formatted_date` parameter, which is not correctly specified in the parameter list of the function there.

Comment: He's asking how to pass the variable from main to this function

Comment: Exactly what I (I'm a she!) am trying to do... I need to pass the values entered into the struct (from the main) into the next function to check the date.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1

```
int is_date_valid(date *d)
{
    //access like d->year
}

main()
{
    date d;
    // get input here
    is_date_valid(&d)
}
```

Method 2

```
int is_date_valid(int year)
{
    // use year here
}

main()
{
    date d;
    // get input here
    is_date_valid(d.year)
}
```

Note: Option 2 works only if use year inside the function

Comment: I'd recommend `const date *d`. Might as well get that right from the start.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I think this is what I was trying to do but wasn't sure about the input value in the function.

Comment: hmm... didn't seem to work... What do you mean const date *d? Would that be the input? I don't really understand what const does yet..

Comment: hmm that didn't sem to work. Now getting the error:
    request for member ‘year’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: @user3306583 did u access like `d->year`?

Comment: What's the difference between accessing it as d.year or d-> year? I'll update my code now so you can see what I have now that's giving the error that "request for member ‘year’ in something not a structure or union"

Comment: access using `d->year` when you have a pointer to the `structure` the same can be written as `(*d).year`

Comment: all `printfs` use `d.year`. plz change to `d->year` or `(*d).year`

Comment: great, changed that and got it compiling now!