# error: request for member ----- in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to access a member of a structure in a function. My struct looks like:

```
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

} date;
```

The date is input by the user in the main. I am then trying to call the date in the following function:

```
int is_date_valid(date *dob) {

    printf("year = %d\n", dob.year);
    //Checking if year is a leap year
    if ( dob.year%400 == 0)
        printf("%d is a leap year.\n", dob.year);
    else if ( dob.year%100 == 0)
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", dob.year);
    else if ( dob.year%4 == 0 )
        printf("%d is a leap year.\n", dob.year);
    else
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", dob.year); 



 return 0;
}
```

This is giving the error in the title of this post. I understand that I am not accessing the year input into the struct but dont' know how to do this? Would appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: `dob.year` should be `dob->year` or `(*dob).year`. hope u did not see my comment in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350755/reading-value-from-struct-in-c/22350841

Comment: You should read a tutorial about `struct`'s and how to work with them. Actually you should already know the answer from your [first question about this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350755/reading-value-from-struct-in-c).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change `dob.year` to `dob->year`.

Use `.` when you have a structure instance.

Use `->` when you have a pointer to a structure instance.

Comment: Do I do that everywhere or just in the if statements?

Comment: I'll add some explaining in the answer...

Comment: ok thanks for that... I added it in the if statements but still getting the same error

Comment: You should change it everywhere else within that function...

Comment: Thanks a lot... understanding pointers, etc a bit better now!