# Programming in C, Stephen Kochan, Chapter 11, Exercise 2

Tags: c

This is my first question on stack.

I have a problem with exercise 2, of chapter 11 - Pointers, in the book Programming in C (Third Edition), by Stephen Kochan.

The question says:
Write a function called insertEntry to insert a new entry into a linked list. Have the procedure take as arguments a pointer to the list entry to be inserted (of type struct entry as defined in this chapter), and a pointer to an element in the list after which the new entry is to be inserted.

My code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct entry
{
    int  value;
    struct entry *next;
};


void insertEntry ( struct entry newEntry, struct entry EntryNo ){

    newEntry.next = EntryNo.next;
    EntryNo.next = &newEntry;
}


int main (){
    struct entry n1, n2, n3, n4, newEntry;

struct entry *listPointer = &n1; // with this pointer we mark the start of the list
n1.value = 100;
n1.next = &n2;
n2.value = 200;
n2.next = &n3;
n3.value = 300;
n3.next = &n4;
n4.value = 400;
n4.next = (struct entry *) 0; // we pinpoint that n4 will be the last entry of our list

newEntry.value = 340;

printf("The list before adding a new entry:\n");
while ( listPointer != (struct entry*) 0 ){
    printf("%i\n", listPointer->value );
    listPointer = listPointer->next;
}
listPointer = &n1;

insertEntry ( newEntry, n3 );

printf("The list after adding a new entry:\n");
while ( listPointer != (struct entry*) 0 ){
    printf("%i\n", listPointer->value );
    listPointer = listPointer->next;
}

return 0;
```

}

And the Output is:

```
The list before adding a new entry:
100
200
300
400
The list after adding a new entry:
100
200
300
400
```

Whereas, when i write the code as seen down below, i get the desired output (which is the new entry among the values 300 and 400.

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct entry
{
    int  value;
    struct entry *next;
};


int main (){
struct entry n1, n2, n3, n4, newEntry;

struct entry *listPointer = &n1; // with this pointer we mark the start of the list
n1.value = 100;
n1.next = &n2;
n2.value = 200;
n2.next = &n3;
n3.value = 300;
n3.next = &n4;
n4.value = 400;
n4.next = (struct entry *) 0; // we pinpoint that n4 will be the last entry of our list

newEntry.value = 340;

printf("The list before adding a new entry:\n");
while ( listPointer != (struct entry*) 0 ){
    printf("%i\n", listPointer->value );
    listPointer = listPointer->next;
}
listPointer = &n1;

newEntry.next = n3.next;
n3.next = &newEntry;

printf("The list after adding a new entry:\n");
while ( listPointer != (struct entry*) 0 ){
    printf("%i\n", listPointer->value );
    listPointer = listPointer->next;
}

return 0;
```

}

And the output is:

```
The list before adding a new entry:
100
200
300
400
The list after adding a new entry:
100
200
300
340
400
```

So the problem is something with the function on the first code, something like the value of the added entry is not registered (or does not return from the function properly). I don't know, as i'm very confused here. If anyone could help me, i would be most grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The arguments to that function should be `struct entry*` instead. I'd recommend reading a little more about pointers and function arguments (call by value vs call by reference) if you have trouble understanding.

Comment: Elaborating on holgac's answer: Even structs can be passed by value (that change happened some time in the 80s). Your `insertEntry()` function operates on a *copy* of the elements and does not affect at all the originals in the list. Your intuition that the change somehow does not "register" was entirely on the spot ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the address of objects to your function. The function prototype will be:

```
void insertEntry ( struct entry *newEntry, struct entry *EntryNo )
```

When calling the function, pass the address as:

```
insertEntry ( &newEntry, &n3 );
```

Also, since we have modified the function to take pointers as arguments, we need to do some modification within the function as well:

```
void insertEntry ( struct entry *newEntry, struct entry *EntryNo ){

(*newEntry).next = (*EntryNo).next;
(*EntryNo).next = newEntry;

}
```

The working code: http://ideone.com/qSdsy0

Comment: Thank you all very much. (although i can only accept one answer) I did some more digging about these and i understand much better now. One more question though, if you could answer. Here: (*EntryNo).next = newEntry; why newEntry isn't assigned as a pointer as well?

Comment: That is because: `newEntry` is already a pointer, we do not need to dereference it.

Comment: Inside the main function, i defined newEntry of type, struct entry ( a struct that has an int, and a pointer of type struct entry). Now in the insertEntry function, i have access on newEntry's address directly, which means i can change the contents inside it's memory address, from that function. However, why can't i assume that for instance newEntry.next isn't a pointer as well? Is it because that, in this function i only provided the address for newEntry (so it doesn't know the address for newEntry.next)?

Comment: next is a pointer, and also a member of the struct. So, instead of `(*newEntry).next`, you can have `newEntry->next`. I hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350755/reading-value-from-struct-in-c Do read the comments, an explanation is also given. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing the objects directly to your function, it works on a *copy* of the objects not the objects itself. In order to work on the objects directly, you need to pass the *address* of the objects.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra Arrays point to the memory address but structs do not.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra I didn't that restriction applied for answers to your own questions.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra , You can accept one of them, though